# Run index.html file before index.php file on browser

Tags: php, html

I have Two file on my Files on my FTP server

```
1 ) index.html
2 ) index.php
```

The index.php file is word-press file and i am using that in index.html through iframe so i want to run index.html not the index.php But the index.php run by default.

And I also don't wanna use .htaccess rule if it is possible

How can i load index.html instead of index.php

Comment: You need to configure your server or do read the file in PHP.

Comment: What do you mean "first"?  Do you want the `index.html` to run, then have `index.php` *appended* to the output?

Comment: If you don't want to use `.htaccess` then use the main server configuration file(s). You have to use *some* sort of server configuration directive if you want to change the logic a server uses to decide what to load.

Comment: it does not make sense to put `index.html` and `index.php` in same folder

Comment: hey ... Who gave me negative point on this question  , this is a very serious Problem ... so please give me plus point

Comment: I gave you a -1 because of your latest comment. a problem can be as much serious as you want, but your question shows lack of effort. See www.whathaveyoutried.com to read HOW to properly ask questions. once you do that, i'll be more than happy to give you my +1

Comment: @STT LCU Oh, i am sorry this is my  mistake .. Next time i will keep that in mind , thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way: rename `index.php` to `index2.php` and link to it from `index.html`.

Comment: Sorry, this can't be possible because the index.php file is word-press file and i am using that in index.html through iframe   
so i want to run index.html not the index.php

Comment: @MuditKumar `index.php` will always run in iframe?

Comment: @MuditKumar if yes, what you are worry about? I think renaming `index.php` to `index2.php` will not affect Wordpress execution.

Comment: No ,Actually it is affecting it , when i change index.php to index2.php , my word-press site stop working  . i am not sure if i need to change the "index.php" name in some other wordpress file where is it included ...

Comment: @MuditKumar [here](http://journalxtra.com/websiteadvice/change-index-php-wordpress-4576/) there is an instruction for renaming `index.php` in Wordpress

Comment: Assuming that your host allows overrides -- .htaccess:
`DirectoryIndex index.html` but mod-rewrites would also be an issue.